# How to efficiently calculate the remainder of a prime factorial divided by a prime number (where Wilson's Theorem is insufficient)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, factorial

This'll be my first question in the Mathematics section, I've stumbled upon here quite a lot, so here I stand before you today to ask a question myself...

There's this question which I've been unable to solve for years. It's from some nationwide competition held in Turkey.

The question asks the following:

```
(20!*12!) mod 2012 is equivalent to which of the following?
A) 344
B) 1062
C) 736
D) 162
E) None of the Above
```

The answer is:

> E

Do note that:

> A valid answer would be 1684

Now sure, I could just plug this into a calculator and find the answer... But how were the poor kids who took this exam meant to solve it?

Through several reductions I myself was, and several other people I've asked the question were, able to reduce the problem to the following:

```
4*[ 60 * 11! * 19! mod 503 ]
```

Now that still looks terribly ugly, what I've really been searching for is an easy way to calculate `11! mod 503` and `19! mod 503`. Is there any theorem or the such which will allow me to easily calculate `the Remainder of a Prime Factorial Divided by a Prime Number`. (And yes, I can assure you that 11, 19 and 503 are all prime numbers.) Any help would be much appreciated, thank you all in advance...

Comment: Given your "note", I don't get how the answer is not E.

Comment: Did you read the second spoiler :P and the "Now sure, I could just plug this into a calculator and find the answer... But how were the poor kids who took this exam meant to solve it?" part?

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't even see the first one. Wacky! Sorry. haha.

Comment: Are people required to calculate this under 1 minute? Else if you give me 5 minutes, I can calculate the given thing mechanically using basic congruences. You don't kneed to calculate 11!*19! yo calculate the remainder mod 503. Once you have that, use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: 150 minutes for 50 questions, let's say it'd take 3 minutes.

Comment: I still don't quite get how one can use the CRT with a common modulus. Don't I need at least two?

Comment: We can rule out B and D immediately because they are not multiples of $4$.

Comment: Given the time constraint it sounds like you are to use a trick or three. Like Ross Millikan, I first thought about checking mod four, ruling out B and D. Next I tried quadratic residues. I'm sure I used the allotted 3 minutes (pencil & paper) to prove that all of $20! \cdot12!$, $344$ and $736$ are quadratic residues modulo $503$, so no cigar for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (potentially) faster method:

The primes under $20$ are $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19$, and the primes under $12$ are $2, 3, 5, 7, 11$.

The largest power of a prime $p$ that divides $n!$ is $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^3}\right\rfloor + ...$

This approach only takes a couple seconds for the small primes and very quickly converges to powers of $1$, which you know will repeat for the rest of the primes. We see the following:

$$20! \bmod{503} \equiv 2^{18} \cdot 3^{8} \cdot 5^4 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \bmod{503}$$

$$12! \bmod{503} \equiv 2^{10} \cdot 3^5 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \bmod{503}$$

Multiplying these two, we get:

$$12! \cdot 20! \equiv 2^{28} \cdot 3^{13} \cdot 5^6 \cdot 7^3 \cdot 11^2 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \bmod{503}$$

And from here you can regroup powers, simplify, reduce, etc. Alternatively, compute $12! \bmod {503}$ by itself first and then multiply it by $2^8 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2\cdot 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \bmod{503}$, which would carry it to $20! \bmod{503}$ (if you wish to deal with smaller exponents).

I think most people would require more than $3$ minutes to solve this kind of problem. But I imagine there are other problems that would take fewer than $3$, so it may balance out.